# CUDA programming is possible on AMD Radeon HD 7640G Graphics Integrated laptop?

Tags: gpu, nvidia

Can I do CUDA PROGRAM ON AMD Radeon GC? Or it's possible on NVIDIA graphics card only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CUDA is a proprietary technology of nVidia, so it only works on their own GPUs (not even on all).

I'll seriously advice against using CUDA because it is platform and vendor limited, even though there are more CUDA libraries and tools at this moment, OpenCL is the preferred option and as such it will inevitably catch up. OpenCL is a generic compute abstraction, it can work on a variety of gpus, cpus and even on more recent tablet and phone SOCs and even on some more exotic chips.

Comment: Can we say OpenCL an alternative of CUDA?

Comment: It is essentially the same tool, just a different implementation. CUDA is somewhat more mature and more resources are invested in assisting developers, while OpenCL is the more open, more portable/supported and more available alternative that will eventually catch up. I think OpenCL for nVidia is actually implemented on top of CUDA. Also, if you care about performance, OpenCL + Radeon will give you way better bang for the buck than CUDA + GeForce, especially for double precision calculations.